# Android: can not access files created by my application after reinstall my application

Tags: android, file, mediastore

I have application that create files in shared storage, i use [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) to create and read files, my application success create and read files, but after i uninstall and reinstall again my application can not access the files created before, even though i check using file manager the files still exist. so, how to access the files created before uninstalled after i reinstall again?
Thank you

this is my code to create files

```
String db_name = c.getString(R.string.db_name);
String backupDbName = "backup-"+utility.getCurrentDateTimeNoSpace()+"-"+db_name;
File currentDB = c.getDatabasePath(db_name);
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
FileChannel dst;
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = null;

ContentResolver resolver = c.getContentResolver();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, backupDbName);
values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE, backupDbName);
values.put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + File.separator
                    + c.getString(R.string.app_name)+ "-" + BACKUP + File.separator + DATABASE);
Uri fileUri = resolver.insert(uri, values);
pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "w", null);
dst = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor()).getChannel();
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
src.close();
dst.close();
if(pfd != null) pfd.close();
```

this is code for read the files

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private Cursor getFiles(String folderName){
    String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

    String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH+" = ? OR "
            + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH +" = ?";

    String rel_path = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + File.separator
            + c.getString(R.string.app_name)+ "-" + BACKUP + File.separator + folderName;

    ContentResolver resolver = c.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);

    return resolver.query(uri, projection, selection,
            new String[]{rel_path + File.separator, rel_path}, null);
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed your reinstalled app can not read the old files. Thats how its made. The new install is like a different app. You can use SAF to let the user choose a directory or a file.

Comment: Blackapps, i do not find your comments very helpful in general. You do not explain why things no longer work, probably due to android 10. Neither do you explain saf, storage access framework. The poster does not require the filepicker.